# How to update azure ml workspace service image id?

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I have workspace service created in machine learning workspace
How can I update ACR repository name and tag in running service ?

https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/cli/ext/azure-cli-ml/ml/service?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_cli_ml_az_ml_service_update

This does not show any arguments related to image id update

az ml service update --name

Answer (score 0):

To update the service to use a new entry script or environment, create an [inference configuration file](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/machine-learning/reference-azure-machine-learning-cli.md#inference-configuration-schema) and specify it with the ic parameter.

Using the CLI

You can also update a web service by using the ML CLI. The following example demonstrates registering a new model and then updating a web service to use the new model:

```
az ml model register -n sklearn_mnist  --asset-path outputs/sklearn_mnist_model.pkl  --experiment-name myexperiment --output-metadata-file modelinfo.json
az ml service update -n myservice --model-metadata-file modelinfo.json
```

Comment: do you any example for modelinfo.json ?